# Sql – Insert value in first empty cell of column and show ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I have a SQL statement that will insert a value into the first empty cell. If I run the PHP script again then it inserts into the next null cell etc.

Problem: I also want to find out the ID of that row, and the value of another column in that row. In the MySQL table below, I want a value inserted in the first ‘null’ of COLUMN A, and also know the ID and value in COLUMN B corresponding to that (i.e. ID= 3 and COLUMN B= 11).

My_TABLE

```
ID   COLUMN A   COLUMN B
1       6             78
2       7             90
3      NULL           11
4      NULL           5
5      NULL           123
```

The following sql statement in PHP script will make it possible to insert value to the first empty cell in COLUMN A:

```
UPDATE My_TABLE
SET COLUMN A = 83
WHERE COLUMN A IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

Result will be:

```
ID  COLUMN A    COLUMN B
1   6             78
2   7             90
3   83            11
4   NULL          5
5   NULL          123
```

I also want to have an SQL script that will print within PHP (echo) the corresponding values of the ID and COLUMN B of the last updated COLUMN A null value (i.e. ID= 3; COLUMN B= 11).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?php
// just in case, for comparison
$q = 'SELECT `id`,`colB` FROM My_TABLE WHERE `colA` IS NULL ORDER_BY `id` LIMIT 1';
$row = $pdo->query($q)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
  // voialà, the value for COLUMN B is now known
  list($id, $colB) = $row;
  $q = 'UPDATE My_TABLE SET `colA`=? WHERE `id`=?';
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);
  // voilà, your row is updated
  $stmt->execute(array($valueForColumnA,$id));
}
```

Beware, do not copy and paste whis nilly-willy. Read it, look at it, smell it and understand it. Any questions?